# Выражение "третьего дня"

Tags: старая-грамматика

Если читать романы писателей 19 века, то обязательно наткнешься на выражение "третьего дня". При этом почти никогда не увидишь выражение "четвертого дня" или второго.
Что такое это "третьего дня" и почему по отношению к другим дням это выражение не применяется?
Моя версия - это "позавчера" или "три дня назад". Но, опять же, почему "четыре дня назад" уже не годится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ТРЕТЬЕГО ДНЯ, в знач. нареч. ***То же, что позавчера".*** Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д. Н. Ушаков. 1935.
> "Третьего дня — нареч. обстоят. времени разг. ***Накануне вчерашнего дня; позавчера".*** Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.

Как видите, третьего дня - это устаревшее слово. В современном русском соответствует "позавчера". Но в русском нет слова, которое обозначало бы "накануне позавчерашнего дня",поэтому, видимо, и нет выражения ***"четвертого дня".***

Answer (score 4):

Так как это просторечие, то и четвёртого дня сгодится, как и позапозавчера. 
http://melni.livejournal.com/322612.html

Только не очень удобно, затруднено для понимания, "третьего дня" = позавчера не все понимают, а это придётся считать, сколько дней назад.

Просто народ употребляет точные и ясные слова. ПОЗАВЧЕРА - приходится думать:   ПО-ЗА + ВЧЕРА,

а "третьего дня" понятно.

А если кому-то хочется сказать "очень давно, много дней назад, возможно сказать и "позапозапозапозавчера", или "5 дней назад", т.е. "пятого дня", только зачем, если более понятно назвать точную дату? А "седьмого дня" - "неделю назад"?

И зачем говорить "второго дня", если есть привычное "вчера" - прошлым вечером? (прошлый вечер, то, что находится по-за вечером, отсчёт от сегодня в обратную сторону), потому что по-за - движение вдоль и за чем-то.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/168986

А вот ЗАВТРА= ЗАУТРО-то, что последует за утром этого дня.Это привычно и понятно.

Answer (score -1):

Второго дня - это и есть вечор. Вечор, ты помнишь... То есть вчера вечером - прям какой-то плеоназм.