# «Третьего дня» вместо «на третий день»

Tags: синтаксис

Смотрю фильм «Место встречи изменить нельзя», пятую серию.

> Правда, мне Евгений Петрович ещё **третьего дня** сказал, говорит, твоё дело чистое [...]

Насколько нормативна форма «третьего дня» вместо «на третий день»? Если не нормативна, то откуда она в просторечии? Украинизм?

Comment: Повтор вопроса http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/44887/Третьего-дня

Comment: *Евгения Петрович* - сильно.

Comment: Правильно: Гадя Петрович.

Comment: behemothus, исправил :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **«Третьего дня»...**

Есть в словарях. См.:

> [***тре́тьего дня***](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/280226/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE)
>
> *нареч. обстоят. времени **разг.***
>
> **Накануне вчерашнего дня; позавчера.**
>
> *Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.*

Comment: Спасибо! Не знал, что это идиома.

Answer (score 3):

Третьего дня - это не "на третий день" при отсчете от какого-то события в будущее, здесь отсчет идет в прошлое. Выражение  устаревшее или устаревающее (**по факту**), его не все понимают. Проще сказать: три дня назад.

Здесь ещё можно посмотреть ответы: [Третьего дня - это когда? | Большой вопрос .ру](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/269996-tretego-dnja-eto-kogda.html)

**Интересно сравнить**: (когда?) десятого (Р.п.) ноября ― это **десятого дня от начала ноября**. Поэтому  "третьего дня/позавчера" ― это третьего дня (Р.п.)  при отсчете от сегодняшнего дня.

Comment: _Sibylla: Проще сказать: **три** дня назад._ === Нет, не три. _Третьего дня = **Два** дня назад_.

Comment: @slava1947  Совершенно верно. Типичная ошибка тех, кто не понимает, что "пошел седьмой год", к примеру, это - шесть лет прошло, седьмой только пошел. Раньше почему-то люди это интуитивно понимали. Поэтому для них "третьего дня" было вполне четким указателем.

Comment: Да, правильно (третьего дня - это два дня назад),  а как только запутались в арифметике (три? или два?),  перестали говорить: "третьего дня".

Answer (score 1):

Третьего дня (исторически - "третьего дни") - можно объяснить "на третий день, считая назад". Так что это, конечно, не украинизм (с чего бы?), не ошибка, просто подзабытая слегка конструкция.

Интересна сама форма родительного падежа в подобных оборотах. Но если вспомнить, что "сегодня" это всего лишь "сего дня" (сей день в родительном), то и тут все становится прозрачно.

Все остальное - см. первый вопрос на эту тему.
[Третьего дня](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/44887)

Comment: По поводу прозрачности: Вопрос:Что значит выражение третьего дня? Три дня назад или среда-третий день? Ответы:  (1) Это означает число текущего месяца, например, 3 января. (2) Три дня назад. (3) Третий день недели. https://otvet.mail.ru/question/35412732

Comment: "Sibylla да-да. Мне совсем не прозрачно то, о чем вы хотите сказать, давая эту ссылку. ))))  Я-то о прозрачности говорил в связи с родительным падежом. Откуда он там взялся и что означает. Все остальное - да, утратилось у граждан понимание того, что такое "третий" и почему это *не три а два*. Об этом тоже говорил.

Comment: Так ведь Р.п. всех и запутал: граждане не понимают, от чего дни  (два или три) отсчитывать: от сего дня, или от начала недели, или от начала месяца (это ведь тоже не очень прозрачно).

Comment: @Sibylla *Р.п. всех и запутал* - С чего бы? Нет, запутались граждане не понимающие принцип отсчета, по совершенно другой причине. Они и "на девятый день" могут переврать как девять дней спустя. Родительный там рядом не лежал. Да и вообще это совсем не тот предмет, о котором я говорил в ответе. "На защиту не выносится" - как обычно отвечают диссертанты не в меру надоедливым оппонентам.  Если и обсуждать, то без связи с ним, ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Разговорный пласт лексики вполне нормативен ("езжай" вместо "поезжай", например) - в отличие от просторечий.

Я вначале подумала, что "третьего дня" - диалектизм, но нет, словосочетание встречается в русской классике.

[**Третьего дня**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F)

> (разг.) позавчера, на день раньше, чем вчера, два дня тому назад ◆
>   *Позвольте, позвольте, Петров, третьего дня вы говорили совсем противоположное!* А. П. Чехов, «Учитель словесности», 1894 г. ◆ *― Вы,
>   Шариков, третьего дня укусили даму на лестнице, ― подлетел
>   Борменталь.* М. А. Булгаков, «Собачье сердце», 1925 г.

Comment: a) Вы запутались с понятием нормативности. Разговорное - это некая ослабленная нормативность по сравнению с  "общелитературной", дающейся без помет. б) Езжай - сейчас вполне нормативно. А вообще, к чему это разговоры в данной теме?